# how to delete jetty jars from maven repository

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I am using eclipse for my project development. In my pom.xml no where I have added dependency for Jetty jars (jetty-server, jetty-io, jetty-http, ...). But when I run "mvn package" command in my local repository and in my WEB-INF --> lib folder these jetty jars are getting added. But I don't want to use those jars. Can someone please suggest me a way to delete these jars through pom.xml.

In my local repository its getting added in repository --> org --> eclipse --> jetty. I tried to delete it by making use of  tag in pom.xml, but couldn't resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

type `mvn dependency:tree` in console. You will see where from those jars are

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run your maven project from Console with the command `mvn clean package` inside the folder that you have your pom.xml file. With this command you clean your application. Maybe this can remove these libraries

Comment: Hi jjmartinez, I have cleaned and deleted from my local repository as well. But while building it was coming up. As I mentioned that I am not writing dependency for this, mvn clean package doesn't help in this case

Comment: <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
 <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
 <version>2.7.1</version>
 <exclusions>
  <exclusion>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
   <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
</dependency>